# Read and count the number of the entries of zip file in ASP Classic

Tags: asp-classic

I would to know how to read and count the number of entries in zip file in ASP Classic

Thank for everybody

Ponomy

Comment: A good place to start would be [Chillkat's Zip ActiveX](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/zip-activex.asp)

Answer (score 0):

1. install a zip component on the server.
2. In ASP code: set objZipHandler = Server.CreateObject("your.component")
3. Follow the documentation of the component on how to count files inside a zip

`dim objZipHandler, iFileCount`

```
objZipHandler = Server.CreateObject("your.component")
objZipHandler.load("myZipFile.zip")

iFileCount = objZipHandler.countFiles()
response.write "Nr Of Files inside ZIP: " & iFileCount 

objZipHandler.dispose()
set objZipHandler = nothing
```